# Google Sheets missing space between 2 numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I use `.setValue(“42 14”)`,cell in google sheets `getValue()` returns 4214.
But when I use `.setValue(42 9)`, cell in google sheets `getValue()` returns 42 9.
Why!?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem.  In the first case setValue("42 14") is a string and I get "42 14".  In the second case setValue(42 9), the script editor errors since it sees it as 2 numbers which is invalid.

Comment: This might have something to do with how you format your cell. try also `getDisplayValue()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what I missed, I had to change cell format of this sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please explain more or post your code here.

Below code is working fine

```
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').setValue('Hello');
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A3').setValue('42 14');
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A4').setValue('42 9');
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A5').setValue(42.9);
```

Please check the screenshot attached

[image]